# Why does IPOPT still give a solution after a termination status of local infeasibility, numerical error or iteration limit?

Tags: python, julia, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, ipopt

I am solving a NLP in IPOPT and then saving the solution afterwards. I noticed that even when I get a bad termination status of local infeasibility, numerical error or iteration limit IPOPT still returns a solution. Are these solutions useful?

For more context here is what my solution looks like saved as a json:

{"solve_time":5315.037714958191,"optimizer":"Ipopt","termination_status":"NUMERICAL_ERROR","dual_status":"UNKNOWN_RESULT_STATUS","primal_status":"UNKNOWN_RESULT_STATUS","objective":2.386034577709679e7,"solution":{ x =
...
very long solution
}

Comment: I think this would be better asked in the ipopt forum: https://github.com/coin-or/Ipopt/discussions

Comment: Why not? I often like to look at solutions even if not optimal. It can give clues about the cause of the problem and the magnitude of the problem. In my opinion, solvers **should** provide the solution corresponding to the best solution so far.